# Is there a way to say that I could quickly improve a skill?

Tags: meaning

For example, I have beginner-level piano skills, but I'm at a point where I could quickly improve my skill.

I want to say that although I'm a beginner now, if someone teaches me I'll become a good player. I have the capacity to become good.

The only word I can think of is 'developable', but that doesn't seem quite right.

Answer (score 1):

You can just say you started learning Piano but you have the potential to be a professional or you're fast learner and it won't take that long for you to be professional.

Comment: +1 I think 'demonstrating potential' is key here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just beginning at something, you are a *novice*. What's interesting is how people might define the gradations between novice and expert. Here are some gradations from the field of nursing.

> The five stages of proficiency in the novice to expert model are: novice, advanced beginner, competent, proficient, and expert (Benner, 1982).

[Source](https://www.nursingald.com/articles/16408-patricia-benner-novice-to-expert-a-concept-whose-time-has-come-again#:%7E:text=The%20five%20stages%20of%20proficiency,with%20the%20situation%20at%20hand.)

The source text is: Benner, P. (1982). From novice to expert. *American Journal of Nursing*, 82(3), 402-407.

Perhaps you could say you were an *advanced beginner* pianist or a *competent* pianist.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using ***quick study***, which [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quick%20study) defines as:

> one that can speedily learn the essentials of something to be done,
> *especially* : a performer (as an actor, musician) with a gift for
> learning with remarkable speed new material (as lines, stage business,
> scores)

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/a-quick-study) defines ***quick study*** as:

> someone who is able to learn new things quickly

Definition of ***quick study*** by [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+quick+study):

> A person who can learn new material quickly. Primarily heard in US.

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=a+quick+study) has an entry for ***quick study***:

> someone who picks things up fast/learns things fast

The sentence "I'm making great progress in my piano lessons—I'm really a ***quick study***." is an example.